# Container view reload data when becoming visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a parentVC with a container view, i have this container on hidden. When i press a button on the parentVC, the container becomes visible. I want to reload the viewDidLoad when it becomes visible.

I tried in prepareForSegue to create an instance of the child vc and reload the viewdidload like this:

```
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"listZone"]){
        PickerZone *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        destination.parentVC = self;
        [destination viewDidLoad];
        [destination.listZone reloadAllComponents];
```

I also tried to create a method in the child and call it in the parent but it doesn't get triggered.

I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't ever want to be directly calling `viewDidLoad` on a view.  This is called automatically after the view is loaded.  You might want to move some or all of your code to its own method and then call that method both inside that view controller's `-viewDidLoad` method and in your code when you want it to refresh.

Comment: I'm gonna try this, i saw that viewDidLoad and also viewWillAppear are called at start even if the container is hidden.

Comment: i added this method in the child `- (void)reloadData;` and then i called `PickerZone *pickerZone;[pickerZone reloadData];`, i added an NSLog in the method, but it doesn't get triggered, any suggestions?

Comment: i made it work, it had to be like this: `PickerZone *pickerZone = [[PickerZone alloc] init];`